# Smart TV / DLNA video streaming software

Tags: android, video, streaming, dlna

I'm looking for a recommendation for software that runs on Anroid 4.4 (kitkat) and streams live video to a Smart TV that supports DLNA. It must not need a separate USB device for the TV since there is already one for wifi access on the TV. The TV is a Samsung and already connected to wifi and media storage.

I'd rather avoid Chromecast or google-produced software (Chromecase isn't suitable because it needs a USB stick connected). The video must stream from a live website and can't be downloaded.

It does not matter if it's HD or not video quality.

Comment: AFAIK the paid version of *BubbleUPnP* supports this – but due to lack of need, I've not verified it myself, hence just as comment.

Comment: The app is going to be rather dependent on the source of the streaming video.

Comment: the source is a web browser @Huey

Comment: As in the specific site you're watching the video at. To cast from a web browser you're looking for mirroring software to mirror your phone's display on the TV.